# How can I create a AlloyUI DiagramBuilder from the JSON returned by DiagramBuilder.toJSON()?

Tags: javascript, json, yui, yui3, alloy-ui

[`DiagramBuilder.toJSON()`](http://alloyui.com/versions/2.0.x/api/classes/A.DiagramBuilder.html#method_toJSON) returns a JSON representation of the diagram. How can I use this JSON object to create a new `DiagramBuilder` with the same diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `jsonData.nodes` to the [`fields`](http://alloyui.com/versions/2.0.x/api/classes/A.DiagramBuilder.html#attr_fields) attribute of the `DiagramBuilder`:

```
var diagramBuilderJSON = diagramBuilder.toJSON();
new A.DiagramBuilder({ fields : diagramBuilderJSON.nodes }).render();
```

Comment: AlloyUI 3.0 seems to currently have a regression which breaks this. See [AUI-1961](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/AUI-1961) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the result of DiagramBuilder.toJSON() to the fields parameter of the DiagramBuilder. See the example below.

```
jsonData = DiagramBuilder.toJSON();
new Y.DiagramBuilder({
    fields : jsonData.nodes,
    availableFields: availableFields,
    boundingBox: '#diagram-builder-container',
    srcNode: '#diagramBuilder',
    render: true
});
```